# cakephp security - post to controller outside app

Tags: php, security, cakephp, post, cakephp-2.4

my question is, is it possible to post to a controller outside the application?

For example i have a controller action `add` in a `PostsController`.

In my `add.ctp`.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('status', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => 1));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
```

Status 1 means waiting for review. Status 2 means accepted.

I know i can set the status inside the PostController or a default value in the Database. It is just an example because i need to set some hidden values in the view.

My `add` action:

```
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Post->create();
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
        }
    }
```

Is it possible with curl or something else to post to my controller and bypass the waiting for review status?

Or does the security component prevent this?

I am using cakephp 2.4.7.

Thanks

Comment: "_Or does the security component prevent this_" ...you could simply try it, couldn't you? Your question is kinda ambiguous, it's not clear whether _you_ actually _want_ to bypass form tampering or CSRF protection, or if you just want to to know if it's possible because you worry about your applications security. ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: i just want to know if its possible. I am using cakephp 2.4.7. I tested it so far and i was not possible to bypass it. Do you agree?

Comment: Kind of also depends on how the security component is configured. Out of the box security component or have you enabled/disabled/configured/tampered the component?

Comment: I am just using the out of the box security component.

Answer (score 1):

> "i just want to know if its possible."

Yes, it is possible.

If you provide more details about what you're actually trying to do, you'll likely get more detailed answer(s).

Comment: I have a controller where a user can create requests to another user with a specific `request-status`. The user who started the `request`can only set the status to 1 or 2. The user who get the request can only set the status to 3 or 4.  Actually i have 4 actions (for every status) in my controller. My actions: `requesterAccept`, `requesterDeny`, `recipientAccept` and `recipientDeny`. And if the `ricipient` deny the request, the `requester` do not have the possibility to `accept`. The `requester`can only accept if the `recipient` also accept.

Comment: My question is, can someone manipulate the form that the `requester`can accept a rejected (by recipient) `request`. Or is it possible that the `recipient`can access actions from the `requester`? If its possible i have to check in each action if the user has the access to do this action.